# Ubuntu 16.0.4 - cannot connect to mobile hotspot

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, atheros, realtek-wireless

I can't connect to my mobile hotspot, but I can connect to other 2GHz Wi-fi networks. The mobile hotspot does use 2GHz band according to the phone. I can connect to the hotspot from Windows 7.

(Note: [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897001/disconnected-you-are-now-offline) may be similar, but it had limited info)

--EDITS--

- After removing /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf, which was left behind for some reason, lspci's output is correct.

-- End EDITS --

Here is `lspci -knn | grep -A3 Net` output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H126.00 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [105b:e017]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k {was ndiswrapper}
```

Any suggestions?

`rflink -all` output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Note: 'b0p33p' is my hotspot, and 'bdp3107' is my home (confirmed working) router's wifi. Others are just neighbors' networks I suppose.

`iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'` output:

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.`

                ESSID:"bdp3107"
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                ESSID:"BELL900"
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                ESSID:"The Millennium Falcon"
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                ESSID:"NETGEAR24"
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                ESSID:"wififofum"
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                ESSID:"b0p33p"
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                ESSID:"Rogers1101"
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                ESSID:""
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
```

Comment: Why are you using `ndiswrapper`? Remove it.

Comment: I installed ndiswrapper in a failed attempt to use another wifi driver.

I tried using apt-get purge to remove it. That didn't help. Any other way to remove it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I used apt to install it, so I thought using apt to purge it would work. And it sort of did, I guess...  
I just ran 
    `-->$ sudo modprobe -r ndiswrapper` then saw  
   `modprobe: FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.`

Comment: Turns out there was a file just floating around `/etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf`.  After using `fuser` to check if it was use (it wasn't) I removed the file and restarted. `Kernel modules` now says `ath9k` but I still can't connect to the hotspot

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of ` rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Also edit to include results for `iwlist scan | grep cipher` with the hotspot active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use a Wi-fi adapter using the Realtek 8811au chipset instead of the Atheros AR9285 adapter that came with my laptop. It connects to my mobile hotspot just fine. :)

I had to Google for "ubuntu RTL8811AU driver" to install the driver, since the driver that shipped with my adapter wouldn't build.

This is the one I ordered from newegg:

http://www.szedup.com/product-item/ac-dual-band-wifi-usb-adapter-2dbi/